# Encrypting NULL

Tags: java, encryption, block-cipher

While using `Javax.crypto` ciphers (more specific `AES128/CBC/PKCS5Padding`), the `doFinal` throws a `NullPointerException` when passing `null` to it as method args.

Is there a way to encrypt `null` so that when persisting it to the database, I don't store `null` as `null` or something similar?

Comment: I guess the method expects an actual object and not "nothing"...

Comment: Would encrypting a zero-length byte array satisfy your requirement? or do you need to distinguish between empty and null?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't encrypt NULL... encryption requires an input value (which NULL is not). If you absolutely must store an encrypted value in your database, you could check whether the value being encrypted is NULL and cast it to an representative value (empty string, 0, whatever your preference), and upon decryption perform a similar check for that value, and recast back to NULL.  However, in my opinion, this is hacky and should be avoided - it's better not to store any value at all, but I don't know your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Check for null before attempting to encrypt. If it's null, don't encrypt it. Likewise for decryption.

Comment: This does not satisfy 'when persisting it to the database, I don't store `null` as `null`'.

Comment: That's a good point, EJP. I'd advise the OP to reconsider not storing nulls as null in the database.

Comment: Well that may not satisfy his requirement either. He may have a requirement to hide whether a column is null.

Comment: Yes, turns out it's quite difficult to meet requirements if you don't know what the requirements are.